# Doubts on thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new about multithread processing in java and now I have to implement an multithreads module using some legacy classes. I think to have some problem of race condition beacause I'm getting different result between single thread and multi threads execution. My main doubts is the following:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable{

    final private int minIndex; // first index, inclusive
    final private int maxIndex; // last index, exclusive
    final private MyDTO dto;
    private MyService myService;

    public Worker(MyDTO dto) {
        this.minIndex = dto.getMinIndex();
        this.maxIndex = dto.getMaxIndex();
        this.dto = dto;
        myService = new MyService();

    }

    public void run() {
        int countReg = 0;
        if(!initErrors){

            try {
                Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
                for(int i = minIndex ; i<maxIndex; i++){
                    myService.executeCalculation(dto,conn);
                    countReg++;
                }
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
    }


public class MyService{


    //It has some method to get object from the database

    public void executeCalculation(MyDTO dto,Connection conn) {

        //I do some actions and 
        RegolaDAO regolaDAO = new RegolaDAO(conn);
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(conn);
        // I use obj durin the calculation

        }   
    }
}

public class MyObject{

    Connection conn;

    public MyObject (Connection conn){
        super();
        this.conn = conn;
    }
}
```

My service is a stateless object and then don't should make any problem while MyObject is a statefull object and this could be make problem. My main doubt since I' using new keyword for each calculation **MyObject obj = new MyObject();** this help me to prevent race condition.

Is MyObject thread safe? 
Can you give me some suggestion about my implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MyObject thread safe? Can you give me some suggestion about my implementation?

Since `MyObject` has non-final fields (`myService`) then it is considered not thread safe.  If two threads were using the same `MyObject` instance, they could start using `myService` *before* it was properly initialized. As @Peter points out, making `myService` be `final` would solve that particular issue.

Looking at the code, the following lines are making calls to other classes so are candidates for thread-safety issues:

```
if (!initErrors) {
```

I don't see how `initErrors` is defined.  If that is shared between threads then it will need to be `volatile` or an `AtomicBooolean`.

```
Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
```

Is the `ConnectionFactory` thread-safe?  Can multiple threads call it at once?

```
myService.executeCalculation(dto, conn);
```

Same questions for the `executeCalculation(...)` method.  Also, as @Peter points out, the `dto` is being used by the service.  If the service is making changes to the `dto` instance then it will need to be synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `myService` is not being changed, you can make it final.

It appears that your `dto` is shared between threads, I would check that it is read only as well.

Also how is `conn` being passed to `executeCalculation`, you should make sure you are not using a field for this.

Comment: I updated my question, what do you think about MyObject?

Comment: @Skizzo if nothing is shared between threads (as your code suggests) then there won' be any multi-threading problems. If you are seeing problems, it means something is being shared, even if you don't know what it is.

Comment: What do you intent where you said *It appears that your dto is shared between threads, I would check that it is read only as well*  How can I do this?